# Launch redirect url in rel window?

Tags: php, iframe, hyperlink

i'm trying to put a piece of code into my login script. If the users account is a particular type i want it to redirect to another url.

This bit i know how to do. but i want the url window to open in a pretty photo box which i have on my site. It's a kind of css box iframe window. I have the majority of my links opening in them by using this code:

```
<a href="something.php?to=<?php echo "$profile_id"; ?>?iframe=true&height=260"   rel="prettyPhoto[1]">Link</a>
```

But when i try and do that for my redirect function it won't work. Can anyone let me know why this would be, i am typing the code like this:

```
function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
        if ($location != NULL) {
            header("Location: {$location}");
            exit;
        }
    }


 <?php

$account_type = account_type();
while ($acctype = mysql_fetch_array($account_type)) 


 if ($acctype['account_type'] == 'free_member')  {
    redirect_to("chatboard.php?iframe=true&height=260\" rel=\"prettyPhoto[1]\""); 
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a couple things and I am not sure how you have it setup, but this is how it should be

```
 <?php


function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}



$account_type = account_type();
while ($acctype = mysql_fetch_array($account_type)){


  if ($acctype['account_type'] == 'free_member')  {
     redirect_to('chatboard.php?iframe=true&height=260&rel=' . $prettyPhoto[1]); 
    }
}

?>
```

And on your chatboard.php check for the proper variables making sure they are cleaned from possible attacks as well.